# Slim Framework error 405 when methods are POST, PUT, DELETE

Tags: php, post, slim

I'm working on an SLIM API,  using [slimframework](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/) version 3.0 RC2.

I have configured the .htaccess as recommended and have defined endpoints as well.  When fetching via the GET method,  I get the proper 200 response and data requested is properly deployed.

However when using any of POST, PUT or DELETE methods, just get a *405* error message,  which states:

> If your Slim Framework application has a route that matches the
> current HTTP request URI but NOT the HTTP request method, the
> application invokes its Not Allowed handler and returns a HTTP/1.1 405
> Not Allowed response to the HTTP client.

This is the POST endpoint that I'm testing:

```
$app->post('/add', function () {                                                                                  
  echo "post ok";                                                                               
});
```

As I mentioned before,  when using GET,  it works fine even using arguments.

My server is a linux debian jessie,  PHP version 5.6.15.  Actually I'm testing the URI on the browser and also using Postman.  Both give me a 405 error for any of POST, PUT DELETE.

Comment: How are you creating the request to the `/add` endpoint? Can you add your headers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the way.  Instead of using post like this:

```
$app->post('/add', function () {                                          
    echo "post ok";
});
```

Use Js *map*:

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST']'/add', function () {                                          
    echo "post ok";
});
```

Replace the POST method for any other PUT, DELETE, PATCH.....  I've tested with the DataBase and works fine as expected.

Also keep in mind that you may or should require function arguments:

```
function($request, $response, $args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically use the post method, or put or delete depending on what you need. This is from the docs.

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->post('/books', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Create new book
});
```

You cant use $app->get on a post request.

EDIT:

Double check your htaccess file as well and make sure its got:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It was a typo,  actually when using post,  I get the 405 error,  when using get,  just 200.

Comment: @datelligent Are you 100% sure you're posting to the correct location?

Comment: Yes,  even if instead of post I change to get,  in the example above,  I get 200 and correct echo.   But when I change to post,  Get the 405 error.

Comment: Yep: .htaccess checked, and again the same answer: 405.